# Pycharm SciView truncate history

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pycharm

I am trying to create a program that can visualize the change of a portfolio in real time. To do this, I update my data and create a new plot with it. When I run the code below in PyCharm, SciView stops displaying the plots after 30 iterations. Ideally, I would like to have it only show the most recent plot, but it would also be fine if it just truncated the history so that I at least always see the current plot. Is there any way to do this? I tried different ways to close the figures (e. g. using `plt.close()`), but did not achieve the desired result.

Code to reproduce:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random


class RealTimeVisualizer:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def update_data(self, x_value, y_value):
        """
        Appends values to the data arrays.
        """
        self.x.append(x_value)
        self.y.append(y_value)

    def create_plot(self):
        """
        Takes an x and a y (both 1D arrays and constructs a plot from it)
        :return: a pyplot figure object
        """
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

        # Draw x and y lists
        ax.clear()
        ax.plot(self.x, self.y)

        # Format plot
        plt.xticks(rotation=90)
        plt.title('Portfolio')
        plt.ylabel('Value')
        plt.show()
        plt.close('all')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    portfolio_cash = 10000
    tick = 0
    real_time_visualizer = RealTimeVisualizer([tick], [portfolio_cash])
    for i in np.arange(50):
        tick += 1
        portfolio_cash += random.randint(-50, 50)
        real_time_visualizer.update_data(tick, portfolio_cash)
        real_time_visualizer.create_plot()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating a new plot and window every time, you can also **update the current Matplotlib figure data in each iteration**. You then need to view the plot in an interactive Matplotlib environment.

### Live updating Matplotlib plots

You can use code similar to this to update the data inside the plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

plt.ion()  # Set pyplot to interactive mode
fig = plt.figure()  # Create a figure
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)  # Add a subplot to the figure

# Variables for our updating data
x = []
y = []

for i in range(50):
    # Generate random data
    x.append(i)
    y.append(random.random())

    # Update the plot with the new x, y data
    ax.plot(x, y, 'ro-')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

### Allow for interactive Matplotlib mode when using SciView

Deactivate SciView or manually set your backend to another interactive GUI to see the updating plot.
This code snipped automatically chooses the correct backend (same list as in the [Matplotlib code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/91cb8a86485a42dc7d1c0e0a7eb0bf9378468ffe/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L239)):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

candidates = ["macosx", "qt5agg", "gtk3agg", "tkagg", "wxagg"]
for candidate in candidates:
    try:
        plt.switch_backend(candidate)
        print('Using backend: ' + candidate)
        break
    except (ImportError, ModuleNotFoundError):
        pass
```

---

### Applied to your code

Your code with suggested modifications would look like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random


class RealTimeVisualizer:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def update_data(self, x_value, y_value):
        """
        Appends values to the data arrays.
        """
        self.x.append(x_value)
        self.y.append(y_value)

    def update_plot(self, fig, ax):
        import _tkinter
        try:
            ax.plot(self.x, self.y, 'ro-')
            fig.canvas.draw()
            fig.canvas.flush_events()
        # Capture an error in case the plotting window is being closed
        except _tkinter.TclError:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    portfolio_cash = 10000
    tick = 0
    real_time_visualizer = RealTimeVisualizer([tick], [portfolio_cash])

    # Choose the right backend
    candidates = ["macosx", "qt5agg", "gtk3agg", "tkagg", "wxagg"]
    for candidate in candidates:
        try:
            plt.switch_backend(candidate)
            print('Using backend: ' + candidate)
            break
        except (ImportError, ModuleNotFoundError):
            pass

    # Create plot
    plt.ion()  # Set pyplot to interactive mode
    fig = plt.figure()  # Create a figure
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)  # Add a subplot to the figure

    for i in np.arange(50):
        tick += 1
        portfolio_cash += random.randint(-50, 50)
        real_time_visualizer.update_data(tick, portfolio_cash)
        real_time_visualizer.update_plot(fig, ax)  # Update the plot the new data
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here.

The workaround I found is to change the matplotlib backend to plot outside the PyCharm.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('qt5Agg')
matplotlib.pyplot.ioff()
```

Then you have to explicit open a new figure and show

```
for i in range(100):
    plt.figure()
    ...
    ...
    plt.show()
```